# Can one add coursework credits after award of the PhD degree ( that had no requirement of Coursework in Indian University) to be on par with US PhD?

Tags: phd, coursework

I was awarded PhD in 2020 by a University as per regulations applicable at the time of my admission where Coursework requirement was only 4 credits ( One course) + Comprehensive Exam + Publications + Thesis + Viva Voce etc... To get equivalency on par with US university PhDs which have more coursework (say 32 credits of coursework), can I now do additional coursework from other universities and add additional 28 credits of coursework to my already awarded PhD by any means? or Should I show them as postdoctoral courses? How to add value to my PhD with these courses done after PhD?

Comment: I am skeptical that anyone considers a PhD with more coursework to be more valuable.  Has anyone told you that would make a difference?

Comment: Anecdotally, from what I have heard, US PhDs are more valued than Indian ones because the expectations for significance, originality and scope of the dissertation are higher.

Comment: Greetings Sir. After award of PhD, in an interview for a job in a Saudi University, I was asked for my PhD transcript that had only one course and commented that I did not have enough coursework credits like a US PhD. Coursework in North American system is counted beyond the Bachelor degree. In fact, I did my Masters from same university where I was interviewed, with GPA (3.804/4.00). All professors of that university have PhDs from US. I was upset. I have already earned 42 credits after PhD degree. Now my problem is how to add coursework credits earned to an already awarded PhD's transcript.

Comment: *in an interview for a job in a Saudi University* --- But this is only one university. I think you should apply more broadly (several countries, several dozen openings). Or maybe you did apply to many positions and only got one interview? If that's the case, then maybe you were aiming too high with the positions you did apply for. The only thing I can think of for why they would be interested in your coursework is to know your background for various areas they might need courses taught in, and want someone who won't have to "learn along with the students" when teaching the courses.

Comment: *in an interview for a job in a Saudi university* --- this is a country with a well-known reputation for nepotism, corruption, and racism.  The most likely reason you didn't get the job is that it turned out the Dean's cousin's wife's friend's brother was applying, but of course they aren't telling you that.  Also, prejudice against Indians.

Comment: Well said Sir. God bless you for speaking the truth.

Comment: Now I have earned 42 credits after PhD. I wish to get at least these 42 credits transferred to my already awarded PhD's transcript so that I do not face such a situation again. Please suggest if there is any provision/ flexibility in academic regulations any where in academic world (Academia) to earn and add credits after the award of PhD.

Answer (score 2):

The US Ph.D. tradition is a bit sui generis. In order to get admitted to a Ph.D. at an Indian university, you  always need to have an M.S. degree in the subject. In a US type Ph.D., you can get admitted into the program right after finishing the B.S. (which does not have to be in the same subject matter). You can equate the Indian Ph.D. program with the US type Ph.D. program after the comprehensive examination.

The reason that you might feel the need to update your Indian Ph.D. is that US (and Canadian, ...) degrees have usually a higher reputation, because they demand more from a thesis. In Academia, you could upset with good publications, e.g. in Computer Science at highly ranked conferences to which US Ph.D. candidates submit, (which is of course very difficult since you graduated from the program and no longer have easy access to a mentor.) Additional course work will not be impressive and rather seem an indication of a fundamental mis-understanding. In Industry, it is your skills that matter and more academic courses might not be the best way to gain additional skills.

How to add value to your Ph.D. is an important question to you, but the answer will depend very much on your goals and circumstances.

Comment: Greetings Sir. After award of PhD, in an interview for a job in a Saudi University, I was asked for my PhD transcript that had only one course and commented that I did not have enough coursework credits like a US PhD. Coursework in North American system is counted beyond the Bachelor degree. In fact, I did my Masters from same university where I was interviewed, with GPA (3.804/4.00). All professors of that university have PhDs from US. I was upset. I have already earned 42 credits after PhD degree. Now my problem is how to add coursework credits earned to an already awarded PhD's transcript.

Comment: Your real problem might be that the Ph.D.s from the US do not think that your Indian Ph.D. is worth much.

Comment: Is there a way to show them your transcript from your MS?

Comment: My MS was from the Same Saudi Arabian University where I applied for the job and it has 42 credits of Coursework. I already had one more Masters with 52 credits from Indian University. Now I have earned 42 credits after PhD. I wish to get at least these 42 credits transferred to my already awarded PhD's transcript so that I do not face such a situation again. Please suggest if there is any provision/ flexibility in academic regulations any where in academic world (Academia) to earn and add credits after award of PhD.

Answer (score 1):

There would be little point in it actually.

Note that doctoral students in US normally start with only a bachelors and the coursework is to enable them to pass comprehensive exams. They likely need advanced coursework beyond the bachelors. It has little additional purpose other than to assure a broad in-field education.

But you have fulfilled the purpose already.

It might also be difficult to do unless you want to enroll in another degree program, though some universities will let you enroll in individual courses.

I'd spend the effort on research in field, rather than courses, unless a specific course would help in the research.

Comment: Greetings Sir. After award of PhD, in an interview for a job in a Saudi University, I was asked for my PhD transcript that had only one course and commented that I did not have enough coursework credits like a US PhD. Coursework in North American system is counted beyond the Bachelor degree. In fact, I did my Masters from same university where I was interviewed, with GPA (3.804/4.00). All professors of that university have PhDs from US. I was upset. I have already earned 42 credits after PhD degree. Now my problem is how to add coursework credits earned to an already awarded PhD's transcript.

Comment: You would need to convince the university to do that, but I doubt they would even consider it. You have your masters transcript.